# For any random variable with expectation there exists $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $X(\omega)\ge\Bbb E(X)$

Tags: probability, reference-request, expected-value

One property of random variables is that there exists $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $X(\omega)\ge\Bbb E(X)$ (if someone could point me to a proof of that I'd be thankful).

But there are finite variable with infinite expectation, so I was wondering what goes wrong in the above theorem because obviously we cannot have that $X(\omega)\ge\infty$

Answer (score 4):

If no such $\omega$ exists then $Y$ prescribed by $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)-\mathbb EX$ is a negative random variable.

Then on base of $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{Y<-\frac1n\})=P(\Omega)=1$ it can be shown that some $n\in\mathbb N$ exist such that $P(Y<-\frac1n)>0$ which leads in combination with the fact that $Y$ is negative to the conclusion that $\mathbb EY<0$.

This however contradicts that $\mathbb EY=\mathbb E(X-\mathbb EX)=\mathbb EX-\mathbb EX=0$.

This reasoning does not work in the case of infinite expectation. Then we cannot subtract $\mathbb EX$ as we did above.

Comment: The equality before last is a minus

Comment: @badatmath Thank you. Repaired now.

Comment: Why can't we directly say that since $Y$ is a negative r.v. it has a negative expectation? I don't understand why we need to show that $\exists n\ :\ P(Y<-{1\over n})>0$

Comment: We cannot just state that "if $Y(\omega)<0$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$ then $\mathbb EY<0$". It is true, but follows not directly from e.g. the definition of expectation. It needs a proof and I provided one. I fact I proved that $Y\leq-\frac1n\mathbf1_{Y<-\frac1n}$. Then taking expectations on both sides gives the result: $\mathbb EY\leq-\frac1nP(Y<-\frac1n)<0$. The last inequality on base of $P(Y<-\frac1n)>0$.

Comment: In short: everything we say in mathematics (e.g. that a negative r.v. has a negative expectation) must be deducible from definitions. Just "saying it" is not enough.